# User creating n objects in java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java language, and got stucked in something... Couldn't find the answer after looking for hours here, so I think it's not duplicated. Anyway, if it is, sorry. Here is the problem:

I have made an interactive program, so the user could handle it all with inputs (allways in CMD). So i have a class (Student) and the main class (Main). In execution time, if the users type createNewStudent, then a new student is created, with some values that he inserts. But if I call that function again, it will override the student created before. So how can avoid this to happen? Since I want to have multiple students at the same time.

Here is the code:
**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type Help to see commands.");
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputProgram = reader.next();
        while(!inputProgram.equals("End")){
            switch(inputProgram){
                case "Help":
                    System.out.println("Type End to exit.");
                    System.out.println("Type Help to see commands.");
                    System.out.println("Type NewStudent to create a complete student.");
                    System.out.println("Type NewStudentFast to create a student in a fast way.");
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                case "End":
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using me. See you soon!");
                    break;
                case "NewStudent":
                    Student s1 = createNewStudent();
                    break;
                case "NewStudentFast":
                    Student s2 = createNewStudentFast();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not a valid command. Type Help to see commands.");
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
            }
            if(!inputProgram.equals("End")){
                inputProgram = reader.next();
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }

    public static Student createNewStudent(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Student first name.");
        String fName = reader.next();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Student last name.");
        String lName = reader.next();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Student age.");
        int age = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Student degrees (separateds with only a comma).");
        String degreesS = reader.next();
        System.out.println("");
        String[] strArray = degreesS.split(",");
        ArrayList<Integer> degrees = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            degrees.add(Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]));
        }
        Student s1 = new Student(fName, lName, age, degrees);
        return s1;
    }

    public static Student createNewStudentFast(){
        Student s1 = new Student();
        return s1;
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.List;
public class Student{
    private String f_name;
    private String l_name;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList<Integer> degrees = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> professors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Student(String f_name, String l_name, int age, ArrayList<Integer> degrees){
        this.f_name = f_name;
        this.l_name = l_name;
        this.age = age;
        this.degrees = degrees;
    }

    public Student(){

    }

    public void showAverage(){
        float total = 0.0f;
        for(int el : this.degrees){
            total = (total + el);
        }
        total = total / this.degrees.size();
        total = (float)Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
        System.out.println("The average of " + this.f_name + " " + this.l_name + " is " + total);
    }

    public void seeClasses(){
        if(this.classes.size() > 0){
            System.out.println("The student classes are: ");
            for(int i=0; i < this.classes.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(this.classes.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The student has no classes: ");
        }
    }

    public void addClasses(){
        String aClass;
        if(this.classes.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("Studend has currently no classes: ");
        }
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total classes to add: ");
        int nClasses = reader.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < nClasses; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a class: ");
            aClass = reader.next();
            this.classes.add(aClass);
        }
    }
}
```

**Aclaration:** My classes are under construction yet, so maybe you will ask 'Why do you want to do it for?'. There is a reason, like gettin all students and calculating total average, etc.

Comment: Make an `ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();`

Comment: create a `arraylist` to hold the `student` object

Comment: Will try it, thank you both... Didnt think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, like some of the guys here said, you need some form of the `List` interface. `ArrayList<Student>` is the most accessible version and would probably be good for your purposes, and you want to do `studentList.add(new Student(*arguments*))`, which will add it to the end of the list.
To elaborate, when you have a variable, like `s1` or `s2`, it can only reference one variable at a time. It points to a value, like this:

```
s1 --> instance of Student
```

But when you say `s1 = new Student();`, it does this:

```
s1    original instance of Student, which is now disconnected from s1
 \-> new Student();
```

But what happens to the first Student?
When a variable is overwritten, its value hangs around - taking up memory, even though it can't be accessed. It's useless - and soon enough, the Java *garbage collector* will come by and sweep up the useless object. It's now deleted and gone forever, no longer using memory which can now be used for something else, while `s1` now references the new Student object instead.
So, if you want to create an amount of objects, but you don't know how many you want to use, use a flexible collection like a list, which can be added to and removed from at will, without having to worry about your object going missing.